# Basis that generates topologies on the real line

Tags: general-topology

We know $\mathcal{B}  = \{ [a,b) : a,b \in \mathbb{R} \} $ is a basis that generates a topology on the real line. Now consider

$$ \mathcal{L} = \{ [a,b) : a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \} $$

I want to show that $\mathcal{L}$ is a basis that generates a topology on R which is different than $\mathcal{B}$

#### Attempt:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since, a real number always lies between two rationals, we have $ x \in [a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$

Next, Suppose we have $I_1,I_2 \in\mathcal{L}$ such that $x \in I_1 \cap I_2 $. I need to find $I_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in I_3 \subset I_1 \cap I_2 $. Put $I_1 = [a_1, b_2) $ and $I_2 = [a_2,b_2) $. Hence, choosing $I_3 = ( \max\{a_1,a_2\} , \min\{b_1,b_2 \} )$, we have $x \in I_3 \subset I_1 \cap I_2 $.

Hence, $\mathcal{L}$ is basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

As for the next question, suppose both $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{L}$ generate the same topology on $\mathbb{R}$. So, we take an open set of $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}}$, say $[\sqrt{2}, 10)$. But this element is not an open set in $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{L}}$ since $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: I got stuck reading the first line of your proof. "...we have $x\in[a,b)$". How do we know that the inequalities $a\le x\lt b$ hold, nothing has been said about $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s fine as far as it goes, but you’re not quite done: it’s true that $[\sqrt2,10)\notin\mathcal{L}$, but that’s not enough to show that it’s not in $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{L}}$. For that you must show that $[\sqrt2,10)$ is not the union of any collection of members of $\mathcal{L}$. That’s not hard: just show that if $\sqrt2\in [a,b)\in\mathcal{L}$, then $a<\sqrt2$, so that if $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{L}$, and $\sqrt2\in\bigcup\mathcal{C}$, then $\bigcup\mathcal{C}\nsubseteq[\sqrt2,10)$. (In words: if $\bigcup\mathcal{C}$ is big enough to contain $\sqrt2$, it’s also big enough to contain something less than $\sqrt2$.)

Comment: Thanks prof. Brian. One question: What is $\mathcal{A}$ ? you mean $\mathcal{C}$ ?

Comment: @FromCuba: You’re welcome. Yes, it I do; I’ve fixed the typo now.

Comment: Just to see if I am understanding the concept: If you have a topology $T$ generated by a basis $B$, then the elements of the topology $T$ are just arbitrary unions of elements of $B$ ?

Comment: @FromCuba: That’s right. $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a topology $\tau$ if and only if $\tau=\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{C}:\mathscr{C}\subseteq\mathscr{B}\right\}$.

Comment: Thanks again. If you don't mind asking, Can you help me with this problem: I placed on bounty with 100 of my reputation: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016907/basic-question-on-the-topologies-associated-with-the-real-lines

Comment: Can I also show that there does not exist a set $[a,b) \in \mathcal{L}$ so that $[a,b) \subset [\sqrt{2},10) $ ??

Comment: @FromCuba: There are lots of $[a,b)\in\mathcal{L}$ that are subsets of $[\sqrt2,10)$: just pick rationals $a$ and $b$ such that $\sqrt2<a<b\le 10$. But none of those sets includes $\sqrt2$: their union is $(\sqrt2,10)$, in fact.

Comment: So since there are not bases elements $B \in \mathcal{L}$ such that $\sqrt{2} \in B$, then we don't have a base element $B$ such that $B \subset [\sqrt{2}, 10 ) $. Hence, $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{L}$ don't generate the same topology on $\mathcal{R}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @FromCuba: (Sorry to have been away so long.) There *are* members of $\mathcal{L}$ that contain $\sqrt2$: $[0,2)$ is one of them, for instance. The crucial point is that none of them has $\sqrt2$ as left endpoint: what we don’t have is a $B\in\mathcal{L}$ such that $\sqrt2\in B\subseteq[\sqrt2,10)$, and therefore $[\sqrt2,10)$ cannot be open in the topology generated by $\mathcal{L}$.